# Error when creating ASP.NET website in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET.  I open Visual Studio (this happens in both 2008 and 2010) and creating a new ASP.NET website using .NET 3.5.  When I attempt to run the website, a FireFox page opens up and tells me that it can't establish a connection to the server (localhost:####).  There's no helpful error message, just "cannot connect."  What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have local firewall software installed that prohibits access to TCP/IP ports locally? If so, you might want to try opening a port, and using the Project Properties options in Visual Studio to hard-code the local Web server to use that port.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the error when I shut down my firewall.

Comment: is you say to me about firwall, I am not say to close any firewall, just find the web server thats run with the visual studio, open it, and see the port.

Answer (score 0):

If you select your website in Visual Studio, you can set 'Use dynamic port' to false. Than you can configure to use a port which your firewall doesn't prohibit access to. (often 8080 is chosen, as 80 is already in use).

To be sure you port is open, configure your firewall to let your application have access to that port.
Completely shutting down your firewall is not what we are recommending I believe.

By the way, if you are new to Visual studio and asp.net and creating websites, I recommend, depending on what you way want to do look into the difference of asp.net website and asp.net web application.
(asp.net web application is only available in the payed versions though I believe...)